# WebGL: viewpoint inside a polyhedron

Tags: webgl

What's the simplest way to render the "inside" on a polyhedron in WebGL?

In other words, I want an octagonal prism (like a cylinder) that's "hollow" and I want to be "standing" inside of it. That's all.

Comment: Probably need more detail to answer this. I'd say three.js would provide the easiest API to do it. Or are your polygons getting culled because of winding? In which case you could turn culling off or switch between gl.FRONT and gl.BACK. Anyway, check out this link: [link](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-cylinder-with-three-js/)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing at your problem, but typically polygons are drawn single-sided -- that is, they don't render when you see them from behind. This is more efficient in most cases.

If the polygons are disappearing when the camera is inside the solid prism, consider either rendering them two-sided (if you want to render BOTH inside and outside at different times), or just reverse the winding (vertex order) of your polygons, or reverse the one-sided polygonal culling state (back/front) of OpenGL to show you the backs rather than the fronts.

Answer (score 0):

Most WebGL frameworks turn on culling so WebGL/OpenGL culls back facing triangles.

You can make sure culling is off with

```
gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE);
```

You can enable culling with

```
gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
```

If culling is on you can chose which faces WebGL culls. By default a back facing triangle is one where in screen space the vertices go in clockwise order. For most 3D models that's faces when viewed from inside the model. To cull those back facing triangles you can use

```
gl.cullFace(gl.BACK);
```

Or you can tell WebGL to cull front facing triangles with.

```
gl.cullFace(gl.FRONT);
```

[This article has a section on culling](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-part-1-orthographic-3d/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the framework you use, you might use something like below:

- Draw the object
- Ensure culling is disabled (GL_CULL). In three.js you can use "`Doubleside`" property for the object
- Translate the viewer position (or the object) so that the viewpoint is inside the
  object. For example `three.sphere.translate`